# Recursive Compounding Interest

Tags: c++, recursion

I have to rewrite this as a recursive function, and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I've googled and googled and seen many different ways, which just makes it even more confusing.

```
float Total(float ir=0, int time=0)//Savings Procedure
{
    float bal = Balance;
    for (short i = 0; i < time; i++)
    {
        bal += (Balance*((1.0+ir)/time))/100;
    }
    return bal;
};
```

My attempt:

```
float compoundit(float balance, float ir, int time)
{
    if (time < 0)
    {
        return balance;
    }
    balance = balance * ((1.0 + ir)/time);
    return compoundit(balance, ir, --time);
}
float TotalRecursive(float ir=0, int time=0)
{
    return compoundit(Balance, ir, time);
};
```

Am I even close? Sometimes I just get 'inf' as a result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One error that I see is you will end up dividing by zero since you stop recursion not when `time` is zero but when it is less than zero.

Comment: That explains the inf result, I changed it from 1 to that just to see if there would be a different result. Thanks. Can anyone explain why my results are so far off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your function to compute the total balance using compound interest is not correct.

After couple of cosmetic changes, tt should be:

```
float computeIterative(float Balance, float ir=0, int time=0)
{
    // The total balance is same as the initial balance if 
    // time is zero.
    float bal = Balance;
    for (int i = 0; i < time; i++)
    {
       // Compute the interest for this period
       float interest = bal*ir/100;

       // Add the interest to the balance so the interest
       // for the next period is a compound interest.
       bal += interest;
    }

    // The total balance after all the interests have
    // been compounded.
    return bal;
}
```

A recursive version of that function would be:

```
float computeRecursive(float Balance, float ir=0, int time=0)
{
   if ( time == 0 )
   {
      return Balance;
   }

   float interest = Balance * ir/100;
   return computeRecursive(Balance + interest, ir, time-1);
}
```

Working code: http://ideone.com/W5ExPT

Answer (score 0):

Consider this part of your code:

```
if (time < 0)
{
    return balance;
}
```

Okay, at this point we know that `time >= 0`. Next:

```
balance = balance * ((1.0 + ir)/time);
```

So `time` could be zero in the above expression. And what happens when you divide by zero in IEEE floating point? You get infinity.

Aside from that, you have another bug. You divide by `time`, but you're decrementing `time` on each recursive call. In the original function, you don't decrement `time`. So in your recursive version, you need to pass both `time` and the number of recursive calls you've made, as separate arguments.

Note also that the original non-recursive `Total` is also broken in at least two ways, so it does not give calculate compound interest correctly either.

Comment: Nice! Now I get a small margin of error. I replaced time < 0 to index < 0 and made the index value what is decremented. Result: Balance after 7 years given 10% interest = 1761.161987
Balance after 7 years given 10% interest = 1742.000000 Recursive Calculation

Comment: Can you explain whats wrong with the Total non-recursive method?

Comment: Lol, I'm stupid, its just returning the original balance.